How to replace a column value with a value from dictionary based on another column value
I have the following Data Frame:
ID    Unique_value    
red_1        0  
red_2        1
blue_1       1                
blue_2       2           
blue_3       2             
blue_4       3         
blue_4       1          

There are two dictionaries for mapping for red and blue ID's :
red_dict = {0: "A", 1: "B", 2: "C"}
blue_dict = {0: "D", 1: "B", 2: "E", 3: "F"}

Desired Output is:
ID    Unique_value    
red_1        A  
red_2        B
blue_1       B                
blue_2       E           
blue_3       E             
blue_4       F         
blue_4       B          

What I have done so far:

Created two dictionaries.
In a for loop, loop through each value in ID column, if the ID value is related to red, then replace the unique_value column with another value.
I am stuck in how to replace that one value from a dictionary of values.


I would create a column using a function of those two columns, as in this answer

Also, you should include the code you've written in your post

I would extract the key (red/blue/…) with a regex and use a dictionary of dictionaries and groupby.apply to map the values:
mapper = {'red': {0: "A", 1: "B", 2: "C"},
          'blue': {0: "D", 1: "B", 2: "E", 3: "F"}}

df['Unique_value'] = (df.groupby(df['ID'].str.extract('([^_]+)', expand=False),
                                 group_keys=False)['Unique_value']
                        .apply(lambda g: g.map(mapper.get(g.name, {})))
                     )

Or using a list comprehension with zip:
mapper = {'red': {0: "A", 1: "B", 2: "C"},
          'blue': {0: "D", 1: "B", 2: "E", 3: "F"}}

df['Unique_value'] = [mapper.get(d, {}).get(v) for d, v in 
                      zip(df['ID'].str.extract('([^_]+)', expand=False),
                          df['Unique_value'])]

If you expect a unique match for each row, it's also possible to craft a DataFrame, stack and merge:
mapper = {'red': {0: "A", 1: "B", 2: "C"},
          'blue': {0: "D", 1: "B", 2: "E", 3: "F"}}

df['Unique_value'] = df.merge(pd.DataFrame(mapper).stack().rename('X'),
                              left_on=['Unique_value',
                                       df['ID'].str.extract('([^_]+)', expand=False)],
                              right_index=True, how='left')['X'].values

Output:
       ID Unique_value
0   red_1            A
1   red_2            B
2  blue_1            B
3  blue_2            E
4  blue_3            E
5  blue_4            F
6  blue_4            B


Since you seem to construct the dictionary manually anyway, you could also include the color in the keys, like this:
mapper = {
    "red_0": "A",
    "red_1": "B",
    "red_2": "C",
    "blue_0": "D",
    "blue_1": "B",
    "blue_2": "E",
    "blue_3": "F",
}

Then you could replace the integer part from the ID column with the values from the Unique_value. partition can be helpful here, allowing us to do:
df["Unique_value"] = (
    df.ID.str.partition("_")
    .drop(2, axis=1)
    .assign(Unique_value=df.Unique_value.astype(str))
    .agg("".join, axis=1)
    .map(mapper)
)

Explanation:
df.ID.str.partition("_") creates a dataframe that looks like this:
      0  1  2
0   red  _  1
1   red  _  2
2  blue  _  1
3  blue  _  2
4  blue  _  3
5  blue  _  4
6  blue  _  4


.drop(2, axis=1) gets rid of the rightmost column,
.assign(...) adds the Unique_value instead, as str because we want to
.join the columns row-wise in the next step so we can
.map the mapper.


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['red_1', 'red_2', 'blue_1', 'blue_2', 'blue_3', 'blue_4', 'blue_4'],
                   'Unique_value': [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1]})
red_dict = {0: "A", 1: "B", 2: "C"}
blue_dict = {0: "D", 1: "B", 2: "E", 3: "F"}

color_dict = {"red": red_dict, "blue": blue_dict}

df["Mapped_value"] = np.where(df["ID"].str.startswith("red"),
                              df["Unique_value"].map(red_dict),
                              df["Unique_value"].map(blue_dict))


print(df)
"""
      ID     Unique_value     Mapped_value
0   red_1             0            A
1   red_2             1            B
2  blue_1             1            B
3  blue_2             2            E
4  blue_3             2            E
5  blue_4             3            F
6  blue_4             1            B
"""

